# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol with CMake and directories C and C++

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm new to CMake and also new to compiling mixed source, I have received the following errors while trying to compile using CMake and Visual Studio 14.0

`(Link target) ->
 main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ethash_get_cachesize
 main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ethash_get_datasize`

The layout of my project is like this:

I have `ethash_get_cachesize` and `ethash_get_datasize` defined in internal.c in  a directory ethminer/libethash/  these are C source. im sure that the CMake file that came with this set of sources is ok as the project has compiled before without issue, it has only given me LINK problems after i have added the following:

I have another directory /ethminer/dag/ with a C++ source "dag.cpp" and "dag.h" these are both C++ files. and the CMake file.

```
set(SOURCES
    DAG.h DAG.cpp
)

include_directories(BEFORE ..)

link_directories(BEFORE ..)
```

the C++ source file "dag.cpp" includes `#include <libethash/internal.h>`

however I fear that I am missing something to tell CMake or Visual Studio to find the files it needs from the directory containing "internal.c"

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I see no command which **links** with a library, compiled from "internal.c". If you look for a way how to do this, see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library). You also may find useful question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix, which describes possible reasons of "unresolved symbol" error.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev , im really struggling with this, 2 days of trying to get this unresolved external working, i dont understand im doing wrong here, i have included the line `target_link_libraries(dag ethash)` in my CMake file, but now i have Cmake throwing errors.. im really frustrated, i cant seem to find any real examples on the internet how to make sure something is linking using CMake..  any help ??

Comment: `but now I have Cmake throwing errors` - Show that errors.